# banner design creator - measurements

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm creating a banner design creator (so people would be able to make their own designs with it's own texts, background, images, shapes and so on). I have various of sizes of my producs for example: 800x2000 mm, A4(210 x 297mm), 3300x2200mm.

For painting I'm using html canvas. I stucked on sizing the canvas. What's the best way how to handle different measurements with proper user experience? (canvas with width 3300 would not be the good).

Currently I have this code:

```
var proportion = variant.width >= variant.height ? variant.width / variant.height : variant.height / variant.width;
canvas.setDimensions({width: variant.width * proportion, height: variant.height * proportion});
```

Comment: Why not make it the screen width/3 or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is one way to have your banner creator be responsive to display size:**

1. Calculate the proportional scaling factor required to make your banner fit on the display size.

   ```
   var displayWidth=1366;
   var displayHeight=768;
   var bannerWidth=3300;
   var bannerHeight=2200;

   // calculate the scaling factor required to make the banner fit on the display
   var scalingFactor = Math.min((displayWidth/bannerWidth),(displayHeight/bannerHeight));
   ```
2. Resize your canvas (it now fits the display but has the same proportions as your banner).

   ```
   canvas.width=bannerWidth*scalingFactor;
   canvas.height=bannerHeight*scalingFactor;
   ```
3. Apply a background color to your banner (if desired).

   ```
   context.fillStyle='Gainsboro';
   context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
   ```
4. Apply the scaling factor to your actual banner text font size.

   ```
   // Scale a real banner 300pt font to display proportionally on the canvas
   // The text on the canvas will be proportionally sized to the real banner size
   var fontSizeInPoints=300;
   fontSizeInPoints*=scalingFactor;
   context.font=fontSizeInPoints+'pt Verdana';
   ```
5. Let the user position text on the banner.

   ```
   // draw the text "Fun!" at the mouse position
   context.textAlign='left';
   context.textBaseline='top';
   context.fillText('Fun!',mouseX,mouseY);
   ```
6. After the user has positioned their text on the scaled-down canvas, you can convert their mouse position back to "real world" coordinates by dividing the mouse coordinates by the scaling factor.

   ```
   // convert mouse coordinates back to coordinates on the real banner size
   var realBannerX = mouseX/scaleFactor;
   var realBannerY = mouseY/scaleFactor;
   ```